# How to link a view to a user profile created using views

Tags: views, users

I created a view which displays users on my site.  In the view, the "name" of users links to their individual profile.

Now i want to have more control over information displayed to users when they view other peoples profile.

To achieve this, I am of the opinion that i need to create another view to display the user profile. Where i see a challenge ahead is how to make my first view link to the individual user profile based on my new view.

Please, how do i achieve these or is there a better way?

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Means you have 2 views, one for USERS listing and when ever the user click the one of the user you want to show user details using another view right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this will help  you,

As I understand you have 2 views, first view is to list the users and the second view is to show the particular user detail information.

In Drupal 7 you can achieve it easily.

Let say the first view path will be **users/listing** and the second view path is **user/%/other**.

Steps

- In first view where you are listing all the users, add another field **UID** and pull it to the top and **exclude it**.

  [image]
- And go to **USER NAME** field and *uncheck* **Link this field to its user** and goto **Rewrite results** and *check* **Output this field as a link** and enter **user/[uid]/other** and save it. [uid] is taken form the **Replacement patterns**

  [image]
- Now its time to create new view which will be showing the user information based on the *user id*. In this view we need to add the contextual filter, based on that the user detail will be shown.

  [image]
- Add contextual filter

  [image]

Comment: Thanks for the extensive and elaborate explanation. Works fine.

Comment: Please can this be adapted if the initial view is in a block? (as it does not have a path) Thanks!

Comment: Of Course You Can do it. The links of the users will remain same for the initial view.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you relate the user to a form he or she submitted, using the data module, schema module, and mysql views module. Assuming you are using a mysql backend. This video shows you how: http://vimeo.com/18701843